# WebRTC with Odoo (formely OpenERP)?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, odoo, webrtc

Is there a way to integrate WebRTC with Odoo. So far I have not found any information how Could I do it.

Libraries outside Odoo like `peer.js` (http://peerjs.com/) work fine on any webserver. But I can't move it on Odoo server as it either does not recognize html and or javascript (or I'm puting in the wrong place) when I try to add script and html code inside qweb template. Or it does not recognize javascript type when I just try to insert html and script code inside `<![CDATA[]]>` inside same qweb template. Then I start getting errors that script type was `text/javascript`, but it was transferred as `text/html`.

I also tried to insert scripts inside template like this:

```
<xpath expr="." position="inside">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/website_dod/static/src/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/website_dod/static/src/js/peer.js"></script>        
</xpath>
```

But I got error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: util is not defined` (line - `util.inherits(Peer, EventEmitter);`) in `peer.js`, even though it does not give such error when you run on other webserver, for example on python SimpleHTTPServer.

Whole example I'm trying to run can be found here: https://github.com/peers/peerjs/blob/master/examples/videochat/index.html

It is likely I'm doing something wrong or it just it's not possible to properly integrate WebRTC with Odoo?

P.S. I'm trying it on master Odoo version (which is release candidate)